# Spring constructor injection with FXML

Tags: spring, custom-controls, javafx-8, custom-component

I have searched for the answer, but i could not found too much.
What i have found: http://steveonjava.com/javafx-in-spring-day-2/ 
That is a good post about how to use spring for controllers, but it say that you cannot use constructor injection. That would not be so big pain, it is just not so clean for me.
The issue come up when i would like to use custom controls (or custom components). Custom controls are created by javafx so that will not be in spring context.

The issue is that with the given solution only the controllers will be created by spring. I have found a possible way that can be done. thanks to https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/fxml-custom-components-using.html articel. But i would like to generalize that solution. So the plan is to write my custom BuilderFactory and Builder implementations, which is required a lot of reflection.

What do you think about this approach?

Every idea is welcome

Comment: See if my example [here](https://github.com/james-d/SpringFXExample) helps. I use Java config here, and it uses constructor injection for the controllers. I experimented with using a `BuilderFactory` and `Builders`to enable custom components to be Spring-managed beans: it worked just fine. Not sure I still have the code anywhere. The basic idea is to write a `BuilderFactory` that wraps the default `JavaFXBuilderFactory`. Check to see if the type passed in has a spring bean and return a builder creating it if so, otherwise delegate to the default factory. There isn't much reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use a `BuilderFactory` to do this. The code is not too bad at all, because the default builder factory is implemented in public API as `JavaFXBuilderFactory`. Thus you can simply delegate to that if there is no bean of the appropriate type in the application context.

Basically:

```
private Parent loadFXML(ApplicationContext applicationContext, URL fxmlLocation) 
        throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlLocation);

    // load controllers from application context:
    loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);

    // load controls from application context, where available:
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new BuilderFactory() {
        JavaFXBuilderFactory defaultFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();

        @Override
        public javafx.util.Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
            String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(type);
            if (beanNames.length == 1) {
                return new javafx.util.Builder<Object>() {

                    @Override
                    public Object build() {
                        return applicationContext.getBean(beanNames[0]);
                    }

                };
            } else {
                return defaultFactory.getBuilder(type) ;
            }
        }
    });

    return loader.load();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I plan to do something like this. But have you tested this solution with @FXML annotation? I did something similar, but that did not worked well, because builder had no methods for parameters.
I will try out your solution. As i can see you are not using custom controls in your project. I have seen many controllers. I would like to create custom events with handlers, those should be injected by java fx

Comment: Hmm. Not entirely sure what you mean. I would imagine that if you wanted the controls to be spring-managed beans, you would use Spring injection to initialize them, instead of initializing them in FXML. The `@FXML` injection works just fine, the `FXMLLoader` gets the controller class from wherever is specified in the controller factory (i.e. from Spring in this case), and then injects the `@FXML`-annotated fields from the `fx:id`s in the usual JavaFX way. I haven't used custom events at all. Perhaps post some code in your question showing what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry for being so slow, but i had to check your solution. Unfortunately i could not make that work. Can you please check what did i wrong you can find my sample here: https://github.com/gege83/javafxCustomComponenetWithSpring

Comment: OK, so there's a ton of errors there. I did actually get it to work, just going through and fixing them one by one. Way too much to document here, but start by fixing the Spring configuration, then fix `MyCustomControl.fxml` so that is uses `<fx:root>` (and just fix the obvious XML errors); in `MyCustomControl.java`, as mentioned before, you need to use a standard `FXMLLoader`, not the `SpringFXMLLoader` and follow the custom control pattern. I took out all the zenjava stuff from the maven config.

Comment: Fist i would like to say sorry about that sitti work i have presented to you.
Finally i managed to work I will leave that repository as a reference.

Thank you for your help again